# Cassandra Copy Issue

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I have this csv file which I am trying to copy into my cassandra table. This is the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE keyspace.mytable (
    A int,
    B text,
    C text,
    uuid text,
    D text,
    E boolean,
    F text,
    G text,
    PRIMARY KEY (A, B, C, uuid)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (B ASC, C ASC, uuid ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'unchecked_tombstone_compaction': 'true', 'tombstone_compaction_interval': '1200', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.LeveledCompactionStrategy'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

I am getting this issue when I try to use this copy command:

```
COPY keyspace.mytable FROM 'data.csv' ;

<ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:244 no viable alternative at input ',' (...769,'2015-01-22','XYZ, QRT Campaign Yay','9e1bda3c-f547-4d8f-af5d-4c0649697ca8','true',[ABC],...)">
Aborting import at record #202. Previously inserted records are still present, and some records after that may be present as well.
```

Answer (score 0):

So this line has your clue...

```
[Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:244 no viable alternative at input ','
(...769,'2015-01-22','XYZ, QRT Campaign Yay','9e1bda3c-f547-4d8f-af5d-4c0649697ca8',
'true',[ABC],...)">
Aborting import at record #202.
```

It looks like the line with `,'2015-01-22','XYZ, QRT Campaign Yay',` is missing a single quote.  Which suggests that `COPY` had a hard time parsing it, so I would think that line in your file has an extra single quote in the `QRT Campaign Yay'` field.

One thing you could try, is to set a different `QUOTE` identifier; but it really depends on how your file looks.  The quick fix would be to edit that line, and either remove or escape that single quote.

Comment: This 'XYZ, QRT Campaign Yay' is actually one string that belongs to the column C

Comment: @blackmamba In that case, specify `WITH QUOTE='` on your COPY command, so that the comma in that string isn't getting parsed into separate colmns.